# Random number generator name of obj input is not defined

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, scope

I am trying to write a simple random number generator, just starting to learn python, but I have programmed in C and matlab, probably to my detriment. I was thinking the problem with my code is that of scope, but I can't figure out what the first while loop should have as a condition if I move obj inside of the first while loop. My code is below, and the error I get follows that.

The input I use is `y`. My question really isn't concerning the random number generator, or putting some of the code in functions, as I can work on that later. This is a first attempt at learning 
syntax, etc.

#### Code:

```
import random
count = 0
obj = 'y'
exit = 0

while obj.strip() != 'n' or obj.strip() != 'N':
    count = count + 1; #counter keeps track of number of random dice rolls
    if 1 == count:
        print 'Welcome to Random Number Generator'
        print'Your first roll is a', random.randrange(0,10)
        print ''
    elif 1 < count:
        print random.randrange(0,10)

    while obj.strip() != 'y' or obj.strip() != 'Y' or obj.strip() != 'n' or obj.strip() != 'N':
        exit = exit + 1;
        obj = input("Continue? Y/N")
        if 1 < exit:
            print 'Invalid input!'
            print 'Please press Y to continue or N to quit.'
```

#### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "RandomNumber.py", line 32, in <module>
        obj = input("Continue? Y/N")
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python 2 (and you are, trust me), you should be aware that `input` will get something from the user *and then try to evaluate it.*

That's why it's complaining about the name `y`. You enter `y` in response to the question `Continue? Y/N` and it then merrily goes of to try and *evaluate* your input.

In fact, if you place a `y = "n"` line before your input statement, you'll experience much angst and gnashing of teeth as you try to figure out why it's ignoring your requests to continue :-)

To see this in action, try to enter `7 + 2` into the following program:

```
print input("? ")
```

You'll see it outputs `9`.

You should use `raw_input` instead, it's the one that *doesn't* try to evaluate what you give it (if you change `input` to `raw_input` in the above program, the output is `7 + 2` rather than `9`).

In Python 3, `input` acts in a less, er ... surprising manner.

Comment: That's the problem, thank you. That's such a simple problem, I should have been a little more thorough in my google search of input()

Answer (score 0):

The first line inside of your `while` loop has a semicolon.

```
while obj.strip() != 'y' or obj.strip() != 'Y' or obj.strip() != 'n' or obj.strip() != 'N':
    exit = exit + 1;   <---------- here
    obj = input("Continue? Y/N")
    if 1 < exit:
        print 'Invalid input!'
        print 'Please press Y to continue or N to quit.'
```

Comment: Whoops, that's a habit from matlab. Removing that doesn't change the error, however.

Comment: You're getting the same exact error when you remove the semicolon? Did you possibly mess up the indentation when you deleted the semicolon?

Comment: I don't think so. I would have suspected that was the error, but it doesn't seem to fix it. I double checked my indentation.

Comment: The semi-colon is fine (syntactically, anyway). It's used to separate multiple statements on a single line (e.g., `print 1; print 2`) but can just as easily be placed at the end of a line as in `print 3;`.